# Can I downgrade to an earlier version of Android after installing an OTA update?

Tags: nexus-7, downgrade

I installed the KitKat upgrade on my Nexus 7, but I am unhappy with it. Is it possible to roll back to an earlier version of Android (Jelly Bean)?

Comment: There are no OTA's for downgrading. However as you have a nexus 7 you can easily download the factory images of 4.3 oder 4.2 for your Nexus 7 from the following site https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images and flash your nexus 7 back to whatever version you like.

Comment: @DanHulme: indeed. I will delete my comment then ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible.

One of the advantages of rooting is the ability to control the operating system that resides on your phone.

With that control, you can change the version of Android. There are two ways to go about doing this:

1. Flash the stock image https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images
2. Install a custom ROM. If you know what an operating system is on a computer, a ROM is basically an OS for your phone. Just check XDA-developers for some great custom ROMs that offer any Android experience, with additional features!

I know for a fact Cyanogenmod still haven't released a KitKat based version and offer a close to stock (unmodified) experience with features that are actually useful. I would recommend to try them out.

Enjoy the freedom!

Comment: Trying this (4.4.2 back to 4.3.1) I get "Device version-bootloader is 'FLO-04.02'. Update requires 'FLO-03.15'."

Comment: Both of the methods I have listed require (to my knowledge) you to have an unlocked bootloader. Please note downgrading and unlocking the bootloader wipes all user data. This is why you should unlock the bootloader earlier, not later ;) To unlock the bootloader of a Nexus device just run `fastboot oem unlock` in the same directory on your computer that you have the fastboot binary.

Answer (score 3):

- Download factory image for your device from the official source
- Extract image (you can use 7zip to extract *.tgz files)
- Download and install ADB,    Fastboot and drivers (install system
  wide). Download from here: 
  http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=48915118
- Connect your Nexus device to the computer with USB cable
- Turn off your device
- Boot your Nexus to bootloader mode by pressing and hold Volume
  Down + Power buttons until you see bootloader menu
- On your       computer open terminal (win+r -> cmd.exe -> enter) and
  go to the       folder extracted in the second step (this folder
  should contain       flash-all.sh file)
- Run flash-all.sh command in terminal

Take this [instruction from here](http://druss.info/2014/12/how-to-downgrade-nexus-from-5-0-to-4-4/)