# Can I downgrade from Kitkat to JellyBean on my Moto X?

Tags: downgrade, moto-x

I have a stock (non-rooted) Moto X that 'upgraded' itself to Kitkat recently.  Is it possible for me to go back to Jelly Bean?

(Deliberately leaving out the reasons since that's not the point of the question.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I downgrade to an earlier version of Android after installing an OTA update?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/57792/can-i-downgrade-to-an-earlier-version-of-android-after-installing-an-ota-update)

Comment: I'm not VTCing this question, because I think the steps for downgrading a Moto X will be different from the steps for downgrading a Nexus device.

Answer (score 4):

The full guide can be found [here](http://www.android.gs/downgrade-restore-moto-x-stock-android-os/) but i've included the steps below in case that page is not available.

**NOTE: All of your personal information, data, accounts and so on will be deleted so make sure you have a backup**

> On your computer Android SDK must be installed: learn [how to install Android SDK on Windows](http://www.android.gs/install-android-sdk-adb-windows/), or [learn how to set up ADB on MAC OS X / Linux](http://www.android.gs/install-set-up-adb-mac-os-x-linux/).
>
> Also, on the same computer the [Moto X drivers](https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/88481/action/auth/session/L2F2LzEvdGltZS8xMzg1NTY4NzEzL3NpZC82N2lQcXBHbA==) must be installed.
>
> 1. Download the RSDLite app from [here](http://d-h.st/wJh).
> 2. Save the file on your computer.
> 3. Also, install the program.
> 4. Get the Moto X stock Android OS from [this](http://sbf.droid-developers.org/ghost_rcica/list.php) page.
> 5. On your computer, unzip the downloaded update file.
> 6. Then, from the folder that will be created right click on the file
>      with .XML extension.
> 7. Select “open with” followed by “notepad” or any other XML editor
>      from your computer.
> 8. Find the following string and delete it: “step operation=”getvar”
>      var=”max-download-size”.
> 9. Save and close the notepad window.
> 10. Open the RSDLite program on your computer.
> 11. Take your Moto X and connect your phone with the PC via USB cord.
> 12. On your PC now open a command prompt window (start -> run -> cmd).
> 13. On the cmd window type: adb reboot bootloader.
> 14. Your phone will be rebooted in fastboot mode.
> 15. From RDSLite, click on the three-dot browse file button and select
>        the .XML file.
> 16. Up next, click on “start”.
> 17. Wait while the process is running on don’t press anything else.
> 18. When the firmware is successfully installed you will be able to
>        unplug the USB cord.
> 19. Good; now reboot your smartphone.

Answer (score 0):

The first Android version of the Moto X was Android 4.2.2 Jelly Bean. As a consequence you can downgrade your Moto X until Android 4.2.2 only, not Ice Cream Sandwich (Android 4.0.x).

Comment: This is not an answer, would be best made as an edit or comment.

Comment: Why isn't it an answer? It may be wrong (because OP is confusing - "ICS" in title, and "Jelly Bean" in body) but it is a valid answer.