# Downgrade nVidia Shield to Android 4.4 KitKat

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, 5.0-lollipop, downgrade, nvidia-shield

I mistakenly installed 5.0 Lollipop on my nVidia Shield tablet, and I regret it. Is there a way to revert back to KitKat? I've tried finding a way, but no luck so far.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I downgrade to an earlier version of Android after installing an OTA update?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/57792/can-i-downgrade-to-an-earlier-version-of-android-after-installing-an-ota-update)

Comment: Also check https://github.com/drtaglia/drtaglia.github.io/issues/13 for the steps

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to flash a factory image to your tablet, which would restore it to the state it was when you first bought it.

Depending on your model (wifi, or wifi + lte), you can find official factory images to for the SHIELD tablet on this nvidia website:

https://developer.nvidia.com/develop4shield

Following the relevant links, you will get to a website from where you can download the factory image. The bundle should also contain instructions. Hope this helps.

Comment: canot download any factory image from https://developer.nvidia.com/develop4shield, any sugestion? Nvidia show to me the message "require registration", but i was logged in yet... edit: i found this: http://drivers.softpedia.com/get/Tablets/NVIDIA/, but nos is a official source...

Comment: @Carcheky I just tested the link and it works for me.... Did you click the Download OS Images button?

Answer (score 1):

I have just gone through the whole process successfully. Below you find all the necessary steps for a downgrade for **OSX** (and likely for **linux**).

#### Install the Java8 Runtime

from here: https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?locale=en_US
after installing, verify from command line if this runs without issues

```
java --version
```

#### Download the Android SDK

Obtain it from: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html
Then you have to execute this command to download fastboot:

```
./android update sdk --no-ui
```

#### You only need the fastboot executable, which you can easily find:

```
~/Desktop/SHIELD/android-sdk-macosx: find . -name fastboot
./platform-tools/fastboot
```

#### Then add its directory to the path:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$PWD/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools"
```

#### Download the Factory Reset Images

From https://developer.nvidia.com/gameworksdownload pick the **NVIDIA SHIELD Tablet WiFi Recovery OS Image** for linux. **Make sure you download the Update 1.2.1**, this is the last one before Lollipop was introduced (I also tried with the factory image, but the tablet was freezing very often). Then, unzip it **from the command line**, then execute the shell file.

```
unzip extract-nv-recovery-image-shield-tablet-wx_na_wf-19485_417.6426.sh.zip 
chmod +x extract-nv-recovery-image-shield-tablet-wx_na_wf-19485_417.6426.sh
./extract-nv-recovery-image-shield-tablet-wx_na_wf-19485_417.6426.sh
```

Everything that follows is performed in the folder where you unzipped (it contains a few *.img files)

#### Put your SHIELD tablet into fastboot mode:

- Turn off the device
- Press "Volume Down" -> "Power", hold "Volume Down" and leave Power buttons till device boots

#### Flash the tablet

```
fastboot oem unlock /// AND FOLLOW SCREEN INSTRUCTIONS
fastboot flash recovery recovery.img
fastboot flash boot boot.img
fastboot flash system system.img
fastboot flash userdata userdata.img
fastboot flash staging blob
fastboot flash dtb tegra124-tn8-p1761-1270-a04-e-battery.dtb
fastboot reboot-bootloader
```

#### Reboot the device

Use the volume up/down and the start button to select "reboot" when the commands above have completed.

#### Reference to the official instructions (not as verbose)

https://developer.nvidia.com/sites/default/files/akamai/mobile/docs/HowTo-Flash-SHIELDTablet-Recovery-Image.txt