# NVIDIA SHIELD tablet, how do I return to 4.4 KitKat from Lollipop?

Tags: stock-android

I mistakenly installed 5.0 Lollipop on my NVIDIA SHIELD tablet, and I hate it. Is there a way to revert back to KitKat? I've tried finding a way, but no luck so far.

---

This was the original post:
[Downgrade nVidia Shield to Android 4.4 KitKat](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/88930/how-do-i-return-to-4-4-kitkat-from-5-0-lollipop?newreg=90e4e79fd4f04257b414a1ab3246b572)

**StackExchange doesn't let me comment or reply to this question because I don't have enough reputation... so I am forced to create a duplicate.**

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Please do not duplicate questions. Instead, if you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](http://android.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.

Comment: @Izzy I did not want to duplicate it. I simply had no chance to reply to the original question (I find this exceptionally dumb). Now I have, and if you upvote my answer in the original thread I will simply delete the current questions.

Comment: Ah – lacked rep (the other question was protected, so you'd needed 10+ rep to post there). Now that you were able – and your answer over there is much more detailed – you might consider deleting your question here ;) Btw: There are ways to quickly gain some rep (at least when it comes to so little as 10). Creating dupes always makes a bad impression – though in an "afterview" your move can be understood. Good luck further here on ASE, and thanks for your contribution!

Answer (score 0):

the whole downgrading procedure for NVIDIA SHIELD on OSX is reported here:
https://github.com/drtaglia/drtaglia.github.io/issues/13

Comment: I upvoted your answer so that you can have enough reputation to answer on that question. Now as you have enough rep, please answer on that question, **and** elaborate the answer, not a link-only like this. After having done that, please delete this question since this is a dupe. Thank you for your understanding.

Comment: I'd rather comment than answer, but I see that I'd need even higher reputation for that... sigh. I have to say, I don't understand why this reputation system is not shared amongst the stack* sites.